# How should I deal with a vocabulary with many terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, performance

I'm trying to use Drupal 8, but if Drupal 7 is better for that, I'm ready to go back to Drupal 7.

I have a vocabulary that must contain at least 10,000 terms, but they can also become more than 100,000.  For the sake of simplicity, I chose to make only one vocabulary, without hierarchy.

I quickly reached the limits of my server, and I regularly get WSODs,  especially when I try to edit the vocabulary.

I tried to increase the limits of memory (I am under MAMP), but I still have errors. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/Sq

How can I avoid these problems?
Is it preferable to split the vocabulary?

Comment: Way too broad. Many sites out there have thousands of terms or millions of nodes. Sounds more like a server tuning problem?

Comment: It's strange. I'm using MAMP yet, with the default settings. I pushed the limit of the memory to 512M ... Are there any other settings to be made?

Comment: Please post the error message from Apache logs or from Drupal error log when you get a white screen. Also, enabling error display in php.ini can help a lot in this matter

Comment: PHP memory limit over 256MB isn't going to be any more beneficial to you.

Comment: Is it just a matter of loading the taxonomy overview page? Replace it with a paged view for better results? Not really a lot of other information here.

Comment: @IsmailCherri Here is the error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php on line 588 E_ERROR Error in file SqlContentEntityStorage.php at line 588

Comment: @Kevin Thanks Kevin for this solution. Otherwise, there is no other setting that would help? To cut the taxonomy in several is not preferable from a performance point of view?

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu of course if it can be cut, it will be preferable, but if not due to some business reasons, the suggestion of Kevin may be your best option

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't answer it in comment. i'll try to answer here. I've solve similar problem, my solution is using [redis caching](http://drupal.org/project/redis) and [entity cache module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entitycache)

Since then, my site going well with 256MB RAM configuration in php.ini.